# what are the down side when developing adobe AIR application?

Tags: air, desktop-application

hi 
looking into the framework, what do you think about it as development framework for 
cross platform desktop apps 
from first look , i can see that all your source code are not encrypted
also does not support multi threaded
what else i must consider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this website gives a good overview about the pros and contras of adobe air:
http://www.itwriting.com/blog/?p=310

there are already thread here that talk about that issue:
[Advantages/disadvantages of writing a web app using Adobe Air/Java as opposed to platform specfic languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972106/advantages-disadvantages-of-writing-a-web-app-using-adobe-air-java-as-opposed-to)

and if you want to protect your source code, there are some things that will help you:
[high performance encryption in adobe air / flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823633/high-performance-encryption-in-adobe-air-flash)